# Clipping filling the intersection instead of cutting

Tags: inkscape, svg, clipping-mask

I'm fairly new to Inkscape, so I was trying to clip the upper part of this letter "e" with a rounded rectangle, but when I do that instead of getting the usual result of having the area outside the rectangle removed I instead got the intersection of both objects filled up with black, as you can see in this GIF:

[image: GIF showing what is happening]

By the way, if I try to create a normal rectangle and clip the bottom object it clips exactly as intended.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The animation is pretty fast to verify, what's written in the statusbar, but it doesn't look suspicious. Which version do you use/which OS?

Comment: @userunknown I'm using Inkscape 0.92.0 r15299 under Windows 10.

Comment: Well, I use 0.91 on Linux but that does not neccessarily mean, that this is the relevant difference. Maybe someone else can reproduce your problem or not with the same combination.